# C# stripe transfer using token

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe.NET and trying to transfer money to a recipient. I use stripe.js to create a token and I'm not sure which property of the object should be used to hold the token of my new recipient. Is myRecipient.BankAccountNumber the proper field to hold the token?

```
   var myRecipient = new StripeRecipientCreateOptions();
                    myRecipient.Name = username;
                    myRecipient.Type = "individual";
                    myRecipient.Email = user.email;
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this now, Recipients have been deprecated by Stripe [as seen here](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#recipients).